# Google Scripts Format Date Creates Impossible Date

Tags: google-apps-script, date-format, date-formatting

In a very stripped down sense, this is my issue. I am creating a script that will look for a folder with a given name inside a particular folder.  If the script finds a folder with that name, it will move the current document to that folder.  If not, it should create a folder with that name, and then move the document.

The current naming convention on folders is "Billed 6/18", as an example.

Right now my script is throwing the date out in a weird way, and that won't help me with my later search by file name in a string format.

```
function MoveTicket() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var billfold = DriveApp.getFolderById(id)
  var currentdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "M/D") 
  var billfoldname = ('Billed ' + currentdate)
  Logger.log(billfoldname)
}
```

But my log shows [20-06-18 15:41:59:480 EDT] Billed 6/170

I've attempted changing the timezone from GMT-4 to UTC, or changing the date format to M/DD or MM/DD, and I still see the same issue.  Just logging new Date() does show the correct date.

Where is it getting 170 for the date? How can I correct it?

Solved.  Was using D which gave day of the year instead of d which gave day of the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var currentdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "M/d")
```

[Simple Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: There we go, it just happened that the day of the year and the day of the month were 1 day off, and I should have used a lower case m.  Thanks!